# How to display data in matrix form - Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one table structure Like

1)Id
2)Date
3)score

Filtered by date, I can show number of rows (Display field: Score).

and on one page I what to show records of 3 dates (3 consequent dates, Stored in tables).

Format should look like....

**Date1   Date2  Date3**

score    score   score

score    score   score

score    score   score

...      ...      ...

should I create my own model using existing Model Classes?

I don't know what will be in your mind, but can user control help me in this situation?

Please Help me...

**Update on public Demand**

using

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
<% } %>
```

I each record can be displayed easily in index view.

What about above structure??

If you don't get then...

records :

1 21/2/2009 29

2 21/2/2009 50

3 21/2/2009 54

2 21/2/2009 77

2 23/2/2009 55

2 23/2/2009 44

2 23/2/2009 66

2 24/2/2009 53

Display

21/2/2009| 23/2/2009| 24/2/2009

29|          55|        53

50|          44|

54|          66|

77|

Comment: @Mastermind, that's a bit uncalled for. Anyway, @Vikas, could you clarify your question a little more?

Comment: @BobbyShaftoe: Basically, the question is, I need to program something, I don't know how to program [something], tell me how to program [it].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted this from my mind - so there can be typos/errors.

First you need a custom Model:

```
public class ScoreColumnViewModel {
    public DateTime Date;
    public List<int> Score;
}
```

In your Controller create a list of your ScoreColumnViewModel (assuming Linq-To-Sql):

```
var dates = /* dates to select */

var scoreColumns = dates.Select(date =>
    new ScoreColumnViewModel {
        Date = date;
        Score = DB.Scores.Where(x => x.Date == date).
                    Select(x => x.Score).ToList();
    }
).ToList();
```

In your View:

```
<% foreach(var column in Model) { %>
    <table>
        <tr><th><%= column.Date %></th></tr>
        <% foreach(var score in column.Scores) { %>
            <tr><td>score</td></tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
<% } %>
```

In your css:

```
table {
    float: left;
}
```

My solution is not ideal but it could be a starting point for you.